# Safe parsing of innerData in Haxe.xml.Fast with empty content

Tags: xml, haxe

I'm having a hard time, reading innerData, when parsing an xml in haxe, using [haxe.xml.Fast](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/xml/Fast.html).

I'm trying to use these utility functions in a custom Class named `XMLUtil`

```
public static function getNodeNamed(parent:Fast, nodeName:String):Fast {
    if ( parent.hasNode.resolve(nodeName)) {
        return parent.node.resolve(nodeName);
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static function getNodeText(parent:Fast, nodeName:String):String {
    var node : Fast = getNodeNamed(parent, nodeName);

    try {
        return node.innerData.toString(); // Still crashing here, although it's in a try-catch block
    }catch (err:Error) {
        return "";
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I'm parsing a node that don't necessarily have inner data (see 'triggers' node)

```
<dialog id="tut4_2" repeat="2">
        <text>Blah blah blah</text>
        <triggers></triggers>
        <triggered>tut4_1</triggered>       
    </dialog>
```

I'm getting a crash when accessing the node's innerData

```
var triggers:String = XMLUtil.getNodeText(newDialog, "triggers");
```

Here's the runtime error

> ```
> [Fault] exception, information=triggers does not have data
> Fault, get_innerData() at Fast.hx:140
> ```

The weirdest thing that I really don't get, is that i'm calling the `innerData` in a try-catch block, but I'm still having my function crashing.

Why is this happening, and how can I access the `innerData` in a safe and convenient way?

I'm using Haxe 3.1.3 and NME 3.0

P.S I know that Fast is meant to be used with a stricter XML structure, but I'm porting a large XML files collection from an as3 project, and I don't want to change the XML content. I just want to deal with it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> You can have several catch blocks with different types to handle
>   different kinds of exceptions. The type Dynamic will catch all
>   exceptions :

```
try {
   // ...
} catch( msg : String ) {
   trace("Error message : " + msg );
} catch( errorCode : Int ) {
   trace("Error #"+errorCode);
} catch( unknown : Dynamic ) {
   trace("Unknown exception : "+Std.string(unknown));
}
```

If the `catch` statement doesn't match the error's type, said error won't be caught. This is the point of using `Dynamic`. You can also leave off the type for the same effect:

```
catch( unknown ) {
   trace("Unknown exception : "+Std.string(unknown));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be out of date, but I was under the impression that it was necessary to throw an error like so:

```
    var fu:Float;
    var a:Float=5;
    var b:Float=0;
    try{
        fu=a/b;
        throw("error")
    }
    catch(err:String){trace("oops");}
```

I couldn't get the Error type to work. http://old.haxe.org/doc/cross/exceptions

Comment: I think you're right, it must have been the `Fault` type not getting caught as `Error`. But a quick test, replacing with `String` didn't work either. I'll try back later, maybe with other types like `Fault` or even `Dynamic`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but I walked around the issue, by practically copying and altering haxe.xml.Fast get_innerData method, so I have it returning null instead of throwing exceptions

```
public static function getNodeText(parent:Fast, nodeName:String):String {
    var _node : Fast = getNodeNamed(parent, nodeName);

    try{
        var it :Iterator<Xml> = _node.x.iterator();
        if ( !it.hasNext() )
            //was : throw name+" does not have data";
            return null;
        var v = it.next();
        var n = it.next();
        if( n != null ) {
            // handle <spaces>CDATA<spaces>
            if( v.nodeType == Xml.PCData && n.nodeType == Xml.CData && StringTools.trim(v.nodeValue) == "" ) {
                var n2 = it.next();
                if( n2 == null || (n2.nodeType == Xml.PCData && StringTools.trim(n2.nodeValue) == "" && it.next() == null) )
                    return n.nodeValue;
            }
            //was : throw name+" does not only have data";
            trace( _node.name + " does not only have data");
            return null;
        }
        if( v.nodeType != Xml.PCData && v.nodeType != Xml.CData )
            //was : throw name+" does not have data";
            return null;

        return v.nodeValue;

    }catch (err:Error) {
        return null;
    }
}
```